Timefold Vehicle Routing Problem Time windowed - Clinician should return home in-time by EOD after performing visits & lunch break will also be there
Timefold Vehicle Routing Problem Time windowed
There are nurses/clinicians and there are visits.
nurses/clinicians will perform visits starting from home location and travel from visit to visit.
Visits will have time windows.
Nurses/Clinicians will start from home and will return to home after performing various visits
Requirement is to find optimized route for nurses/clinicians.
I have previousVisit and arrivalTime for chaining the visits, clinician starts from home location and goes from visit to visit (this is working fine), now i want clinician to come back to his home location after doing visits within his working hours.
Below is my Visits, Providers and solution class :
@PlanningEntity
@Data
public class Visits {
    @PlanningId
    private String id;

    private Double matrixVisitId;
    private Long clientId;
    private VisitMsa msa;
    private Date[] slotPreferences;
    private String[] products;
    private VisitsMember member;
    private String slotType;
    private boolean pinned;
    private TimeWindow timeWindow;

    private ClinicianSlot assignedSlot;

    private Providers assignedClinician;
    private Visits previousVisit;

    @CascadingUpdateShadowVariable(targetMethodName = "updateArrivalTime")
    private LocalDateTime arrivalTime;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "timeBlockRangeForVisit")
    public List<ClinicianSlot> generatePossibleTimeBlocks() {
        if (this.timeWindow == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<ClinicianSlot> possibleTimeBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
        LocalDateTime start = timeWindow.getStart();
        while (!start.plusHours(1).isAfter(timeWindow.getEnd())) {
            possibleTimeBlocks.add(new ClinicianSlot(start, start.plusHours(1)));
            start = start.plusHours(1);
        }
        return possibleTimeBlocks;
    }

    @PlanningPin
    public boolean isPinned() {
        return pinned;
    }

    @PreviousElementShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "visits")
    public Visits getPreviousVisit() {
        return previousVisit;
    }

    public void setPreviousVisit(Visits previousVisit) {
        this.previousVisit = previousVisit;
    }

    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "visits")
    public Providers getAssignedClinician() {
        return assignedClinician;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getArrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime;
    }

    public void setArrivalTime(LocalDateTime arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void updateArrivalTime() {
        if (previousVisit == null && assignedClinician == null) {
            arrivalTime = null;
            return;
        }
        LocalDateTime departureTime = previousVisit == null ? assignedClinician.getDepartureTime() : previousVisit.getDepartureTime();
        arrivalTime = departureTime != null ? departureTime.plusMinutes(getDrivingTimeSecondsFromPreviousStandstill()) : null;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public LocalDateTime getDepartureTime() {
        if (arrivalTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return getStartServiceTime().plusMinutes(55);
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public LocalDateTime getStartServiceTime() {
        if (arrivalTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return arrivalTime;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public long getDrivingTimeSecondsFromPreviousStandstill() {
        if (assignedClinician == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "This method must not be called when the shadow variables are not initialized yet.");
        }
        if (previousVisit == null) {
            return Constants.getDrivingTime(assignedClinician.getLocation().getCoordinates(), member.getMemberLocation().getCoordinates());
        }
        return Constants.getDrivingTime(previousVisit.getMember().getMemberLocation().getCoordinates(), member.getMemberLocation().getCoordinates());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}

@Data
@PlanningEntity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Providers {

    @PlanningId
    private String id;

    private Integer staffResourceId;
    private String providerId;
    private ProviderMsa[] msa;
    private Client[] clients;
    private String[] products;
    private List<ClinicianSlot> availableSlots;

    @PlanningListVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "visitRange", allowsUnassignedValues=true)
    private List<Visits> visits = new ArrayList<>();

    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    private Location location;

    private LocalDateTime departureTime;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public int getTotalDrivingTimeSeconds() {
        if (visits.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }

        int totalDrivingTime = 0;
        Location previousLocation = location;

        for (Visits visit : visits) {
            totalDrivingTime += Constants.getDrivingTime(previousLocation.getCoordinates(), visit.getMember().getMemberLocation().getCoordinates());
            previousLocation = visit.getMember().getMemberLocation();
        }
        totalDrivingTime += Constants.getDrivingTime(previousLocation.getCoordinates(), location.getCoordinates());

        return totalDrivingTime;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public LocalDateTime arrivalTime() {
        if (visits.isEmpty()) {
            return departureTime;
        }

        Visits lastVisit = visits.get(visits.size() - 1);
        return lastVisit.getDepartureTime().plusMinutes(Constants.getDrivingTime(lastVisit.getMember().getMemberLocation().getCoordinates(), location.getCoordinates()));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}

@PlanningSolution
@Data
public class ProviderRouteSolution {

    private List<Visits> visitList;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "visitRange")
    public List<Visits> getVisitList() {
        return visitList;
    }

    private List<Providers> clinicianList;
    
    @PlanningScore
    private HardMediumSoftScore score;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "clinicianRange")
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public List<Providers> getClinicianList() {
        return clinicianList;
    }
}

Constraint class:
@Service
public class ProviderSchedulingConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    public ProviderSchedulingConstraintProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[]{
                enforceAllHardConstraints(constraintFactory),
                assignVisitToValidSlotAndClinician(constraintFactory),
                penalizeUnassignedVisits(constraintFactory),
                minimizeChainedTravelDistance(constraintFactory),
        };
    }

    private Constraint enforceAllHardConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingUnassigned(Visits.class)
                .filter(visit -> visit.getAssignedClinician() != null)
                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD, visit -> {
                    Providers clinician = visit.getAssignedClinician();
                    boolean msaMatches = (clinician.getMsa() != null && visit.getMsa() != null) &&
                            Arrays.stream(clinician.getMsa())
                                    .anyMatch(msa -> Objects.equals(msa.getState(), visit.getMsa().getName()));
                    boolean clientMatches = (clinician.getClients() != null && visit.getClientId() != null) &&
                            Arrays.stream(clinician.getClients())
                                    .anyMatch(client -> Objects.equals(client.getClientId().longValue(), visit.getClientId()));
                    boolean productMatches = (clinician.getProducts() != null && visit.getProducts() != null) &&
                            Arrays.asList(clinician.getProducts()).contains("CHA") &&
                            Arrays.asList(visit.getProducts()).contains("CHA");
                    return (msaMatches && clientMatches && productMatches) ? 0 : 1;
                }).asConstraint("Enforce All Hard Constraints");
    }


    private Constraint penalizeUnassignedVisits(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingUnassigned(Visits.class)
                .filter(visit -> visit.getAssignedClinician() == null)
                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM).asConstraint("Unassigned Visit");
    }

    protected Constraint minimizeChainedTravelDistance(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEachIncludingUnassigned(Providers.class)
                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
                        Providers::getTotalDrivingTimeSeconds)
                .asConstraint("minimizeTravelTime");
    }

    private Constraint assignVisitToValidSlotAndClinician(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingUnassigned(Visits.class)
                .filter(visit -> visit.getAssignedClinician() != null)
                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD, visit -> {
                    boolean fitsVisitWindow = isVisitWithinMemberTimeWindow(visit);
                    return (!fitsVisitWindow) ? 10000 : 0;
                }).asConstraint("Assign Visit to Valid Slot and Clinician");
    }

    private boolean isVisitWithinMemberTimeWindow(Visits visit) {
        LocalDateTime visitWindowStart = visit.getTimeWindow().getStart();
        LocalDateTime visitWindowEnd = visit.getTimeWindow().getEnd();
        boolean isArrivalAfterWindowStart = visit.getArrivalTime().isAfter(visitWindowStart);
        boolean isDepartureBeforeWindowEnd = visit.getArrivalTime().plusMinutes(55).isBefore(visitWindowEnd);

        return isArrivalAfterWindowStart && isDepartureBeforeWindowEnd;
    }
}

Below are the changes i am planning to make :

adding nextVisit with annotation as @NextElementShadowVariable in Visits.
adding arrivalTime in Providers. (Shift end time)
next visit should be null for last visit and last visit arrival time + 55 mins(viist time) + driving time to provider location should be less than arrivaltime of Provider(shift end time).

is it the correct design ? I will also need to add constraint to check if provider is returning home in time after last visit completion

Something shift hours and overtime in the Field Service Routing model?

@GeoffreyDeSmet i am building using timefold open source, not using api yet so i want to do changes in my model for shift hours etc. Need help with that. ALso i want to incorporate lunch break and no visit or travel should happen during lunch break. Thanks.

We implement lunch breaks etc with a shadow variable of arrival time and start time per visit.

@GeoffreyDeSmet i have shadow variables too as code mentioned in above description, can u give an idea or link so i can follow from there - thanks
